# Functional test to check javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-testing

my requirement is to write a functional test in ruby on rails to check whether javascript is loaded or not. can anyone give me some hint or example so that i can understand, what and how to do with it?

Comment: define loaded, do you mean executed, enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cucumber with capybara to test your views with @javascript tag before your scenarios.

http://openmonkey.com/2010/04/09/javascript-testing-with-cucumber-capybara/

Comment: Yeah, for this use case I also recommend capybara-webkit, it's more lightweight then Selenium and works better then HTMLUnit.